# add Delete button at last column in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am adding columns on `grid-view dynamically`

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("Item Title", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Unit Pack", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Pack", typeof(string));
gv1.DataSource = dt1;
gv1.DataBind();
```

and add `delete button automatically` by

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It shows the gridview like

```
| Delete | Item Title | Unit Pack | Pack |
```

Now i want to Show Delete button at the last column like

```
| Item Title | Unit Pack | Pack | Delete |
```

How can I do this? How to create delete button at last column?

Comment: Checkout the SetOrdinal property - example can be found here http://forums.asp.net/t/1227098.aspx/1

Comment: have you check your `Delete` button alignment after running that page or just check it's design part (without run or debug).plz answer fast.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding column dynamically thats why you need to add delete column dynamic. Or you can add linkButton in RowDataBound:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Row.DataItem != null)
{
    LinkButton lb = new LinkButton();
    lb.CommandArgument = e.Row.Cells[3].Text;
    lb.CommandName = "Delete";
    lb.Text = "Delete";

    e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add((Control)lb);
}
}
```

in rowCommand you can write code for delete:

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
switch (e.CommandName.ToLower())
{
    case "delete":
//your code here
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the RowCreated-event of the gridview, you can push the CommandField to the right:

```
protected void gv1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = e.Row;

    TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
    row.Cells.Remove(cell);                
    row.Cells.Add(cell);
}
```

Thanks to this [blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/03/move--autogenerate-columns-at-leftmost-part-of-the-gridview.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Item Title" HeaderText="Item Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit Pack" HeaderText="Unit Pack" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Pack" HeaderText="Pack" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>\
```

and code background is:

```
dt1.Columns.Add("Item Title", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Unit Pack", typeof(string));
dt1.Columns.Add("Pack", typeof(string));
gv1.DataSource = dt1;
gv1.DataBind();
```

Try this code

Comment: This is not dynamic :/