# Adding a button to the last column of a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This is how i created a grid view in my ASP.NET C# project. This grid has 4 columns. I want to add a 5th column and add a button on each and every row. How can i do this ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"  CellPadding="1" Width="900px"/>
```

Comment: I would suggest adding one button outside of the grid as if you get lots of rows then every time the grid renders, all the buttons gets rendered and the performance will decrease.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Place button as LAST column in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942668/place-button-as-last-column-in-gridview) or [add Delete button at last column in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542092/add-delete-button-at-last-column-in-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` in the gridview markup
2. Define columns as `BoundField` (or `TemplateField` if you wish)
3. Add a`TemplateField` for the button in the last column

Sum up:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1" Width="900px">
    <Columns>
        <%-- <asp:BoundField /> Definitions here --%>
        ...
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button Text="Click ME" runat="server" ID="btn" OnClick="Clicked" />        
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: What about the  `<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server"  CellPadding="1" Width="900px"/>` ? Should i add your code at the end of my `GridView` ?

Comment: You need to define columns manually (in the markup) as `AutoGenerateColumns` need to be set `False`; See slightly updated answer

Comment: After i added the line `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` the other columns are not getting displayed. How can i solve this ? and when it's  `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` it adds the column to the start of the Grid.

Comment: Write `<asp:BoundField DataField="<fieldname>" />` for each column. I have shown where to write those markups. Say, you are trying to show a list of students (name, age as columns). Then obviously your have assigned a datasource in the code-behind. and the type `Student` has fields like name, age etc. You will have to write a BoundField with FieldName = "name" for showing _name_ column, another one for _age_ column

Answer (score -1):

suppose you are binding data table having 4 column say col1,col2,col3 and col4

then your gird view in .aspx will be like;

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1"                 Width="900px" OnRowCommand="gv_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col1">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("col1")%>// "col1" is field of your database
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>  

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col2">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("col2")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col3">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("col3")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>                     

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="col4">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%#Eval("col4")%>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK"  CommandName="show"  />   
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**.cs page will be **

```
protected void gv_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.CommandName.ToLower() == "show")
  {
    //your code on click event 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, But i get an error when i click on the button, it says `Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using ` . ANy clue ?

Comment: I still get the same error. `Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using `

Comment: Downvote for using 1 as your first index.  This is just going to make it confusing in the code behind later.

Comment: @mike col1 is not an index ,i had take it for example ,instead of "col1" you can pass your data base field whatever you want.